# Use maxResults from Youtube v3 APIs on React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, youtube-data-api

I was just working on youtube API in my React app and was wondering if I can change the default number of results with the code below.

It was working perfectly without setting the maxResults value, I hoped someone could help me here on that.

```
import YTSearch from 'youtube-api-search'    

YTSearch({key: API_KEY, term: 'hello world', maxResults: 20}, (data) =>{
   console.log(data);
});
```

Note*: I know it is possible by making it like a http request and put the maxResult in the url but I was hoping to import it in this style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found out the problem source. In order to use Youtube API on a React app which is running on a Node.js server, you need to install youtube-api-search module:

```
>PROJECTDIR npm install --save youtube-api-search
```

I had done this but there is no definition for maxResults in this module so what you should do is going to node-modules folder and find youtube-api-search and just add one line to it:

```
 var params = {
    part: 'snippet',
    key: options.key,
    q: options.term,
    type: 'video',
    ADDED PART>>>>> maxResults: options.WHATEVERYOUWANT
  };
```

then you can use it like below:

```
YTSearch({key: API_KEY, term: 'hello world', WHATEVERYOUWANT: 20}, (data) =>{
   console.log(data);
});
```